# Inserting date in the format mdY with pure MYSQL

Tags: mysql, substring

First of all, the use of any other programming language is not allowed.

Consider a date coming in the string form `mdY` e.g. `1252016` (except that the leading month may be a character length of 1 or 2) is to January 25 2016 as `10252016` is to October 25 2016.

In either case, we would want the substring of the month as either: 
`SUBSTRING( "1252016" , 1, 1 ); => 1` or
`SUBSTRING( "10252016" , 1, 2 ); => 10`.

For example:

```
CONCAT_WS( "-",
    SUBSTRING( "1252016" , -4, 4 ) , 
    SUBSTRING( "1252016" , 1, 1 ) ,
    SUBSTRING( "1252016" ,  -6, 2 ) 
); => "2016-1-25"
```

Is there any way to conditionally get `1` or `2` characters from the start of the string, or otherwise a way to read negatively from the `7` position to the beginning of the string, and REVERSE it?

The reason that using another programming language cannot be used is due to the amount of dating being imported via `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE`. And as far as I understand it, I can only control the structure of the query.

Comment: What would be the correct result for `1112016`? 11/1/2016 or 1/11/2016?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson it just has to insert as a correct `DATE` into the database. Whether the format begins as `mdY` or `dmY` is irrelevant as either one has the potential to have the leading `d/m` as 1 or 2 in character length.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson is correct. Your date format is inherently ambiguous in many cases when you have a seven-digit number.  Your data import effort, as presently specified, won't succeed. If you can get your data source to write `12052016` for 5-Dec-2016` and `01252016` for 25-Jan-2016, you'll have a chance at making this work. But if you get `1252016` you simply can't discern the difference between the two.

Comment: It should be fine. The dates come in as a whole integer, only the leading zeroes would be removed, so there wouldn't be a scenario where the middle part of the date format is less than 2 in length. I can't explain in more detail why it is the way it is but it just is :P, the middle part will have padded zeroes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

pad the string with a leading zero, and then use the `STR_TO_DATE` function:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(LPAD('1252016', 8, '0'), '%m%d%Y');
```